# Ansible - when condition with_item

Tags: ansible

I would like to copy ssh keys to my server via ansible. For this purpose, there is a file in which all users are listed with their name, password, uid, etc. The users are created using this file. For each user in the file, there is a file that contains the public ssh key.
The ssh key files are copied on the basis of the users.
Now, however, it happens that a user has to be created who does not need an ssh key.

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory.yml
├── playbook.yml
└── roles
    └── add_user
        ├── files
        │   ├── user1.pub
        │   └── user3.pub
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── vars
            └── main.yml
```

```
# /vars/main.yml
users:
  - {name: 'user1', groups: 'bla', uid: '6000', userpass: '$y$j9T$VOV'}
  - {name: 'user2', groups: 'blub, uid: '6001', userpass: 'DkEtdH5.Eko4'}
  - {name: 'user3', groups: 'sudo', uid: '6002', userpass: 'H5.Eko4'}
```

```
---
# /tasks/main.yml

- name: add user
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    shell: "{{ item.shell | d('/bin/bash') }}"
    password: "{{ item.userpass }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ users }}"

- name: Deploy Users Public SSH-Key
  authorized_key: user="{{item.name}}" key="{{ lookup('file', 'files/{{ item.name}}.pub')}}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  #when: "{{ key }}" != "success"
```

```
files/
├── user1.pub
└── user3.pub
```

I can simply create a file (userxy.pub) that has no content, that works. But i am looking for a more elegant method.

How can I change my ssh key deployment (name: Deploy Users Public SSH-Key) so that it only runs if there is also a file for the user?

I tried something with

...
with_items: "{{ users }}"
when: "{{ key }}" != "success"

Comment: Does the authorized_keys task fail when the file does not exist? Could you just ignore errors?  `{{ lookup('file', 'files/{{ item.name}}.pub', errors='ignore')}}`. And also set `failed_when` to false for the task? I know it is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The double braces '{{ }}' can't be nested

```yaml
- name: Deploy Users Public SSH-Key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/{{ item.name }}.pub') }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

Fix it

```yaml
    key: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/' ~ item.name ~ '.pub') }}"
```

The code will be simpler when you put the concatenation of the path into a variable. For example,

```yaml
- name: Deploy Users Public SSH-Key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', _path) }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  vars:
    _path: "files/{{ item.name }}.pub"
```

Q: ***"It should only run if there is a file for the user."***

A: The [testing paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) on the controller is trivial

```yaml
- name: Deploy Users Public SSH-Key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', _path) }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  when: _path is exists
  vars:
    _path: "files/{{ item.name }}.pub"
```

(not tested)